# React Native- Off and On button

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm trying to get my button to play my audio file using Expo Audio. When the state is set to "false" it should stop the music and when the state is "true" it should play the music. I'm able to successfully toggle the state from true and false when I press the button and play the audio file but I can't stop playing the audio file. Why isn't my stopMusic() function stopping the audio?

```
const ViolinScreen = ({ navigation }) => {


  const [EString, setEString] = useState(false);
  console.log(EString)

  toggleSwitch = () => setEString(previousState => !previousState); {
   if (EString) {
     playMusic()
   }if (!EString) {
     stopMusic()
   }
 }


async function playMusic() {
  const soundObject = new Audio.Sound();
  console.log("Being hit")

  try {
    await soundObject.loadAsync(require('../../assets/violin/E-0.mp3'));
    await soundObject.playAsync();
  } catch (error) {
    alert("Error" + error.message)
  }
}

async function stopMusic() {
   console.log("Not Being hit")
  const soundObject = new Audio.Sound();

  try {
    await soundObject.loadAsync(require('../../assets/violin/E-0.mp3'));
    await soundObject.stopAsync();
  } catch (error) {
    alert("Error" + error.message)
  }
}
```

and here I try to call it in my onPress:

```
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={ toggleSwitch }
          >
          <Image style={styles.stringButtons} source={ViolinG} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: You're creating a new sound object in both the start and stop functions. You're currently calling stopAsync on a different sound object than the one you're playing.

Comment: Thanks Will! I'm realizing now this is the problem. Just not sure how to work around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`const soundObject = new Audio.Sound();`

This is causing your problem, you create a new object of Audio.Sound() in both play and pause function.

So when you call `stopAsync()` on your `stopMusic` function, it not the sound object that currently playing.

My suggestion is:

```
function playMusic() {
    this.sound = new Audio.Sound();
    ......
    await this.sound.loadAsync(require('../../assets/violin/E-0.mp3'));
    await this.sound.playAsync();

}

function stopMusic() {
    await this.sound.stopAsync();
    ...
}
```

This will assure that the reference you call on both play and stop function is the same.

Hope that help ^^

Comment: Thanks for responding! I tried it this way too but I get an error that says "audio is not loaded". I'm trying to combine the two functions into one (so i don't have to have it load twice) and use an if/else statement but that isn't working either.

Comment: Hmm.. that weird, cause it work fine on my project. Can u tell me which function throw the error `audio is not loaded` ?